# What is the browser support for React and how to overcome compatibility issues?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browser

I am working on chrome version 37 and using React 16. `onClick` functionality is not working in that version.  Actually the browser does not show the event listeners and nothing happens on the click. The code shows no errors.

Specifically, the following does not work:

```
<SelectOption onClick={() => this.handleOptionClick(item) }>
                        <div>{item.image ? that.renderOptionImage(item.image) : null}{item.text}</div>
                        <div>{item.optionalText ? item.optionalText : null}</div>
                    </SelectOption>
```

The complete code is :

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Select, SelectOption, OptionImage} from './styles';

class SelectBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.showList = false;
        this.activeItem = null;
    }

    renderOptionImage(image) {
        return (
            <OptionImage src={image} ></OptionImage>  
        );
    }

    updateActiveItem(item) {
        this.renderSelectedItem(item);
        // display active item in search box
        // var currentElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        // {this.renderSelectedItem()}
    }

    renderSelectedItem(item) {
        console.log("I am here in ter tiem");
        if (item) {
            return (<div>
                <div>renderOptionImage(item.image) {item.text}</div>
                <div>{item.optionalText}</div>
            </div>)    
        }
        else {
            return (<div>Select your Item</div>)       
        }
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({
            showList: !showList
        });
        this.renderOptions();
    }

    renderOptions () {
        console.log(this.showList);
        const that = this;
        var data = [
            {'text': 'Item 1',
             'image': 'http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1',
             'optionalText': 'item 1'
            },
            {'text': 'Item2',
             'image': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg',
             'optionalText': 'item 1'
            },
            {'text': 'Item2',
             'optionalText': 'item 1'
            },
            {'text': 'Item2',
              'image': '',  
            }
        ];
        if (this.showList) {
            return data.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    <SelectOption onClick={() => this.handleOptionClick(item) }>
                        <div>{item.image ? that.renderOptionImage(item.image) : null}{item.text}</div>
                        <div>{item.optionalText ? item.optionalText : null}</div>
                    </SelectOption>);
            });
        }
    }

    handleOptionClick = (item) => {
        console.log('I am handling this');
        // update the select main content
        this.updateActiveItem(item)
    }

    render() {
        const props = this.props;
        const {showList} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Select id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name} >{this.renderSelectedItem()}</Select>
                {this.renderOptions()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SelectBox.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

    SelectBox.defaultProps = {
    name: 'Select yout item from the following',
    id: 'select-one'
};

export default SelectBox;
```

Comment: react should work on all [ECMAScript 5 compatible browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5). Since version 23 chrome fully supports es5. Your issue is likely not related to your chrome version by any means.

Comment: you could likely use an onChange event on the select instead of click events on the options, but try removing the arrow function  and just pass this.handleOptionClick(item) or leave the arrow function and remove the handleOption and just console log something to see if the click event is firing.